# paypal signin page has a broken layout

Tags: css, layout, paypal, webforms

when go to paypal signin page I have page with broken layout ( seems problem in css ). Screenshot attached here https://snipboard.io/QGnx6K.jpg

Strange, but after this stage there is normal style webform but when go to the transfer money there are again css problem and button for transfer just don't work. It disturbs all opportunities

I tried to solve this by clearing cache and cookie browser, use another browser, install another browser but nothing helped. Also this problems reproduced on two my computers but when I tried third computer of my friend - all was fine and I could do transfer.

So how case could be fixed for my computer?

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same thing. And it was all ok like a week or two ago. So I mean it's an issue on their end. Or we have some troubles with Paypal in our region (because the government promised to put some restrictions on Paypal very soon, maybe it has begun already?)

Comment: I just found that when I go trough VPN - all work fine. Otherwise - no. Yes, it seems it is government restriction issue